# Child routes with react-router-config

Tags: routes, react-router, server-side-rendering

I'm working on React SSR, with child routes, but all child routes are being rendered in one single page.

For example:

```
export const routes = [
  // Some sibling routes go here and since this is nested with <Switch>, those are working fine.
  {
    path: '/user/:id',
    component: Userpage,
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/user/:id/profile',
        component: Profilepage,
      },
      {
        path: '/user/:id/posts',
        component: Postspage,
        routes: [
          {
            path: '/user/:id/posts/:id',
            component: Postpage,
            routes: [
              {
                path: '/user/:id/posts/:id/edit',
                component: Posteditpage,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    component: Notfoundpage,
  },
];
```

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      { renderRoutes(routes, initialData) }
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

Using this pattern to print the page:

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';

const Userpage = ({ route }) => {
  const { routes } = route;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        This is the user page
      </h1>
      { renderRoutes(routes) }
    </div>
  );
};

export default Userpage;
```

Renders this at this route, `http://localhost:3000/user/me/posts/firstpost/edit`:

---

## This is the user page

## This is the postspage

Show all posts here

## This is the postpage

Show only one post here

## This is the posteditpage

Edit post here

---

How do I make it so that it renders separate pages, do I need to set all routes as siblings?  This doesn't seem right though.

Comment: By snippets I see, I am not sure that it should be used within Switch, please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-config

Comment: @pwrigshihanomoronimo yeah, that's the same example I see in the documentation.  Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: could you provide link to it (documentation) then. tried to reproduce issue by your code, but it throws error that Switch can not be used outside of Router.

Comment: oops, now I have read your answer again, and looks that you are questioning that for nested routes, all parents are showed, it is intended behaviour. you should put them on the same level then, please check. https://react-router-config.stackblitz.io/child/a/grand-child

Comment: you have 'This is user page' text in layout, which confused me into thinking that all your routes are displaying at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to display parent route layout together with child's, then you should put your child route on the same level as parent. Snippet that demonstrates child route behaviour 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-config

```
const routes = [
  {
    component: Root,
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        component: Home
      },
      { // moved it from 'Child.routes' to the root level
        path: '/child/:id/grand-child',
        component: GrandChild
      },
      {
        path: '/child/:id',
        component: Child,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```